# Convergence of series $\sum 2^n \sin\left(\frac{a}{3^n}\right)$ with $a$ complex numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the complex numbers $a$ (if exist) for which is convergent the series $$\sum 2^n \sin\left(\frac{a}{3^n}\right)$$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727009/for-what-value-of-x-the-following-series-will-converge-sin-x2-sin-frac-x

Answer (score 2):

You have $\sin z\sim z$ when $z\to0$, hence when $n\to\infty$, the summand is equivalent to $a(\frac{2}{3})^n$, which is summable for any $a$.